# how to change method POST to name attrib of submit

Tags: php, ajax, post

For an uploadform i use a form with ajax like below:

form:

```
<form id="sfmFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
    <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" class="buttonUpload" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:this.config.uploadUrl,
            data:data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(rponse){
                $("#"+ids).hide();
                var obj = $(".sfmfiles").get();
                $.each(obj,function(k,fle){
                    if($(fle).attr("rel") == rponse){
                        $(fle).slideUp("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                    }
                });
                if (f+1 < file.length) {
                    self._uploader(file,f+1);
                }
            }
        });
```

and the php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],   "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
        echo($_POST['index']); // to validate
    }
    exit;
}
```

Now i want to change  the method POST to the name attrib of submit:

So the desired php looks like this:

```
if($_POST['submitHandler'])
{
...
```

instead of

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
...
```

What should i change int the ajax to make this work properly?

Update ajax:

```
multiUploader.prototype._uploader = function(file,f){
    if(typeof file[f] != undefined && self._validate(file[f].type) > 0){
        var data = new FormData();
        var ids = file[f].name._unique();
        data.append('file',file[f]);
        data.append('index',ids);
        $(".sfmfiles[rel='"+ids+"']").find(".progress").show();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:this.config.uploadUrl,
            data:data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(rponse){
                $("#"+ids).hide();
                var obj = $(".sfmfiles").get();
                $.each(obj,function(k,fle){
                    if($(fle).attr("rel") == rponse){
                        $(fle).slideUp("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                    }
                });
                if (f+1 < file.length) {
                    self._uploader(file,f+1);
                }
            }
        });
    } else
        console.log("Invalid file format - "+file[f].name);
}
```

Comment: Show how you build the `data` variable for `data: data,`

Comment: You take an awful lot on trust in this code. You dont even check `$_FILES['file']['error']`

Comment: post above updated

Comment: Well if you are using `FormData()` it should already be in the POST array

Comment: I think you don't need to do any changes in ajax just check your php code with isset() `if(isset($_POST['submitHandler'])) {`

Comment: i tried it with `if(isset($_POST['submitHandler'])) {` but he doesnt upload anymore

Comment: your file input name is `multiUpload` and you are using `file`. use `$_FILES['multiUpload']['tmp_name']`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works when i just add method: "POST" in my ajax call

in Data parameter passing type parameter will allow you to distinguish both form values.
and you can get type value with $_POST['type'] in if condition

```
$.ajax({
            method:"POST", //add method post so you can access with $_POST['']
            url:this.config.uploadUrl,
            data:{'data':data,'type':'passTypeName1'},
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(rponse){
                $("#"+ids).hide();
                var obj = $(".sfmfiles").get();
                $.each(obj,function(k,fle){
                    if($(fle).attr("rel") == rponse){
                        $(fle).slideUp("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                    }
                });
                if (f+1 < file.length) {
                    self._uploader(file,f+1);
                }
            }
        });
```

so your server side code will be like this

```
if($_POST['type']=='passTypeName1'){
//code
}elseif($_POST['type']=='passTypeName2'){
//  code
}
```

Comment: yes that also works fine but i already have another form with POST, so i have to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: ok you can  distinguish both with one extra parameter of type in data i am editing the code just take a look on this

Comment: i tried this but still doenst work unfortunately. It only works with: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{`